# URI bad format Silverlight Navigation

Tags: silverlight, navigation, uri

I am making a website with silverlight and I stumbled on this problem;

I created a custom control(Menubutton), which has a Image and a HyperlinkButton

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:l2="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1.Klassen"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MenuButton"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Canvas x:Name="cnvMenuButton" Width="200" Height="50">
            <Image Source="/SilverlightApplication1;component/Buttons/MenuButton1.png" Height="50" Width="50" />
            <HyperlinkButton x:Name="btnLink" Content="HyperlinkButton" Canvas.Left="55" Canvas.Top="14" FontFamily="Lithos Pro Regular" FontSize="14.667" Foreground="Black" Background="{x:Null}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want to use several of these in my mainpage, to navigate a navigationFrame to the desired page. So since the HyperlinkButtons work with the NavigateUri and the TargetName, I changed the code behind the MenuButton page so that I can specify the URI and TargetName from my mainpage

```
public partial class MenuButton: UserControl
{

    public MenuButton()
    {
         // Required to initialize variables
         InitializeComponent();
    }


        public string Titel
        {
            get { return btnLink.Content.ToString(); }
            set { btnLink.Content = value; }
        }

        public string NaviUri
        {
            set {
                Uri naviuri = new Uri(value);
                btnLink.NavigateUri = naviuri;
                }
        }

        public string TargetFrameString
        {
            get { return btnLink.TargetName; }
            set { btnLink.TargetName = value; }
        }

}
```

So after I specify these property's in my mainpage, I get this error :
[net_uri_Badformat] Arguments : Debugging resource strings are unavailable.

code I use in my mainpage:

My Stackpanel with the custom control

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Menu" Orientation="Vertical" Canvas.Top="243" Height="300" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="70,290,0,126">
       <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <l1:MenuButton TargetFrame="contentFrame" NaviUri="Home" Titel="Home"/>
</StackPanel>
```

the contentframe in the same page

```
<navigation:Frame x:Name="contentFrame" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <navigation:Frame.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </navigation:Frame.RenderTransform>
            <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                <navigationCore:UriMapper>
                    <navigationCore:UriMapping MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml" Uri="Home"/>
                    <navigationCore:UriMapping MappedUri="/Views/About.xaml" Uri="About"/>
                </navigationCore:UriMapper>
            </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
</navigation:Frame>
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should include the second parameter to the Uri constructor: UriType.Relative

Comment: This partly worked, he stopped giving the [net_uri_Badformat] error, but now I keep getting the error: The property 'NaviUri' does not exist on the type MenuButton in the XML namespace 'clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1'. But I clearly defined the property in my control?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a slight oversight with your NaviUri property: It doesn't have a get method. There's no way to retrieve the value that is set.

Answer (score 0):

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/dllPageTest;component/PageFromDll.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

This example works!))